# Target iOS 6 (iphone3gs) with Xcode 8.x?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, mfi

I maintain an application that is used by people who have iPhone 3gs devices, the phone is actually part of a mobile barcode scanning application, and uses MFI accessory barcode scanner case hardware with the iPhone inside it.

Until Xcode 8 was released, in Xcode 7, I could still build applications as "iOS 6 and up". It seems this was deleted with almost no discussion or documentation on Apple's site.  Targeting older devices, even though the consumer world may have forgotten about them, is still important to me.

Is there a procedure to use a single Xcode version (8.x) latest and still target iOS 6 targets? (Perhaps by importing resource bundle contents from Xcode  7 manually into Xcode 8's resource folders) Or do people now have to install two Xcode versions (7 and 8) and have two branches of their apps to target everything from iOS 6 to current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the minimal iOS version on xCode 8.* is 8.0. No longer Apple supports iPhones 3 and 4. There is no workaround around this. Just keep xCode 7.

Comment: I have done a bunch more searching and decided this is it.  Since the Xcode project formats appear to be diverging, I created a project file copy and committed them separately so my main project and Xcode 6 each have their own Xcode project files.

Comment: Interesting. Did you actually have build problems with XCode 7 or 8 regarding your project? Or did you make a separate version just to be backward safe since you have to use XCode 7 in case you eventually DID run into problems? FYI, I am in the same boat with an older app that will now have to be built with XCode 7

Comment: I have MFI (accessory) and there are differences in the project, including firmware and support files necessary, for different iOS versions.  I can not test a single version on a single XCode version with different iOS versions and devices either. It's really a horrible mess. If I can't debug and test on my own devices, how can I ship one binary that can't be tested or debugged on one XCode version.